# Wireless not connecting, worked until a week ago

Tags: wireless-networking

Recently the wireless internet on my desktop computer has been failing to connect. When trying to connect , my network shows up, yet I am unable to actually connect to it. This happened to me a few weeks ago, but I purchased a new wireless adapter and it worked fine until now.

The first wireless adapter I had was the model TL-WN781ND. That stopped working after 2 weeks or so and so I purchased a new one.

The wireless adapter model number is TL-WN951N. It is a 300mbps Advanced Wireless N PCI Adapter.

I am using a Belkin router with the model number: F5D7230-4.

Strangely enough, my laptop never fails to connect to the wireless network, yet it is at the same point in the house (my room).

What could possibly cause this to happen, what are things that I should check, and ultimately, what steps should i attempt in order to fix this? (wired network is out of the question).

Comment: Have you considered a laptop problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapters, while they can certainly go bad, are much more reliable than routers. You see questions here all the time where the routers have just gone bad. They also often fail intermittently rather than dropping dead. I have seen it happen with one computer, but not another, so see if you can test your desktop with another router. This could rule out the desktop as the problem. You can also update your network card driver.

Comment: I just reinstalled the drivers for my desktops wifi card, then my wifi started working again. Do i chalk this up to a driver problem and move on, or do i investigate further?